# ajax динамическое обновление без замены

Tags: javascript

Возможно я глупость спрашиваю, но существует ли вывод на ajax таким образом, что бы setInterval не обновлял всё, а добавлял только новое? То есть я выделяю текст и всё сбрасывается.. Это не гуд. Если можно то подскажите с примером. 
Читаю про WebSockets, но для меня это слишком сложно.. Я пару месяцев как начал этим увлекаться.. Пока сложно очень для понимания. 
Спасибо)
Вот мой код:

```
<script>

        function show()  
        {  
            $.ajax({  
                url: "../../ajax/select/dialog.php?komy=<?php echo $_GET['komy']; ?>&avtor=<?php echo $_GET['avtor']; ?>",  
                cache: true,  
                success: function(html){
                    $("#dtr").html(html); 
                }  
            });  
        }  

          $(document).ready(function(){  
            show();  
            setInterval('show()',3000);  
        });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>

    function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "../../ajax/select/dialog.php?komy=<?php echo $_GET['komy']; ?>&avtor=<?php echo $_GET['avtor']; ?>",  
            cache: true,  
            success: function(html){
                $("#dtr").append(html); 
            }  
        });  
    }  

      $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',3000);  
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Но дублируется текст каждые 3 сек. Я так предполагаю нужно что то указать еще в коде

Comment: Можете ссылку дать где это все происходит? а то не очень понятно